# ReactJS Flux Initialize Store Through API Call

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I want to initialize a `store` with data stored in a database. Then I want to call this store from my `Component` to set the state.

```
class BucketlistStore extends EventEmitter {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        request.get(url)
            .set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .end(function(err, response) {
                if (err) return console.error(err);
                this.bucket_list = response.body;
            });

    }

    getAll(){
        return this.bucket_list;
    }
}
```

Then in my components: I want to do something like this:

```
class BucketApp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            bucket_list: BucketlistStore.getAll()
        };
    }
    //...render stuff
```

However, I get this error `Cannot set property 'bucket_list' of undefined` on this line: `this.bucket_list = response.body;`. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: In order to better understand the issue, can you explain why you decided `EventEmitter` ? Is redux not more suited ?

Comment: @yuantonito Actually, I am very new to reactjs and after reading through documentation I came across Flux and Redux architecture. I simply chose to work with Flux since it seemed less complicated for now.